# Add calculated field based on past values of the row SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case, common-table-expression

I have a data set with a date field and column 'X' as shown below. X is a binary field - I want to add a field at the end ('desired field (calculated)') that will give me the first date of where the string of 1's starts for field 'X'. Any ideas? In Excel, I would look at the row before to check if it was blank or not based on the below:

Logic:

> ```
> Case when X=0 then Null 
>      when X=1 and 'desired field value for the row above' = Null, then Date
>      when X=1 and 'desired field value for the row above' != Null, then value of 'desired field value for the row above'
> ) end as desired field
> ```

---

```
Date (dd/mm/yy)|X|desired field (calculated)
01/01/00       | |
02/01/00       |1|02/01/00
04/01/00       |1|02/01/00
10/01/00       |1|02/01/00
20/01/00       | |
20/02/00       | |
20/03/00       | |
04/04/00       |1|04/04/00
06/04/00       |1|04/04/00
10/04/00       |1|04/04/00
20/05/00       | |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(new_grp, grp),
  case 
    when x = 1 then first_value(date) over(partition by grp order by cast(date as date format 'DD/MM/YY'))
    else null
  end desired_field
from (
  select *, countif(new_grp) over(order by cast(date as date format 'DD/MM/YY')) grp
  from (
    select *, x != lag(x) over(order by cast(date as date format 'DD/MM/YY')) new_grp
    from `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
# order by cast(date as date format 'DD/MM/YY')
```

If applied to sample data - output is

[image]

Comment: had to change the new_grp condition otherwise worked great! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative sum to assign a grouping to the `1`s and then spread the value:

```
select t.* except (grp),
       (case when x = 1 then max(date) over (partition by grp) end) as desired
from (select t.*,
             countif(x <> 1) over (order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: thank you! another method that might use fewer resources to excute?

Comment: How large is your data?